# How do I activate a certain block template only when editing the front page?

Tags: block-editor, frontpage

I've chosen a custom page(-post) to be my front page. Now I want to use a block template only on that page, when editing it in the Gutenberg editor. As I understand it I have to add it on "init" or close to it, before I know the post_ID so I can't do a `if ( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) === $post_ID )`.

What are my options?

**Edit:**
I've tried this but since is_front_page() is returning 'false' it doesn't work:

```
function home_block_template() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );

    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $post_type_object->template = array(
            array( 'core/image', array() ),
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'home_block_template' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `$post_type_object->template` seems to be done on 'init' (or close to it) while `is_front_page()` is set later, so I had to use `$_GET['post']` instead. I also changed `get_post_type_object( 'post' )` to 'page'. Like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'home_block_template' );
function home_block_template() {
    if ( ! is_admin() || ! isset( $_GET['post'] ) || get_option( 'page_on_front' ) !== $_GET['post'] ) {
        return false;
    }

    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'page' );
    $post_type_object->template = array(
        array( 'core/list' ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you let me know if you face any problem.

```
function myplugin_register_template() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );

    if( is_front_page() ) {
        $post_type_object->template = array(
            array( 'core/image' ), // add your core/custom blocks here
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_register_template' );
```

Comment: Thanks, but is_front_page() is returning 'false' so it doesn't work.

Comment: Is front page is returning false because that page is not your front page. Set that page as your front page by going into WordPress Dashboard > Settings > Reading menu from sidebar.

Comment: Well, I wish it was that easy. The page I'm looking at is my chosen front page in the settings, it even says so in the posts list.

Comment: May be conditionals are set after `init` hook therefore it is not working. Can you please use `wp` hook instead of `init` and share your findings here.

Comment: Already tried the wp hook. I solved it though, just posted the answer.